# Tell jQuery when URL has ended?

Tags: jquery, youtube, embed, vimeo

I am using the following code to turn a YouTube and Vimeo URLs into embeds:

```
 $('.media-supported li, .blog-post').html(function(i, html) {

    return html.replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/g, '<div class="media-item"><iframe width="940" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>');

});
$('.media-supported li, .blog-post').html(function(i, html) {

    return html.replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:vimeo\.com)\/(?:clip\?v=)?(.+)/g, '<div class="media-item"><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/$1?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="940" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>');

});
```

If they are by themselves it works fine. However when they are wrapped in paragaph they take the closing tag as part of the url.

You can see what I mean in this Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/xH7xK/

Is it possible to tell the code where a URL will finish - perhaps end if < or end if space, or both?

Comment: If nobody responds .. that might be cause anyone is watching videos

Comment: @roXon, everyone but me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your regular expression into this:

```
html.replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?([^<\s]+)/g, '<div class="media-item"><iframe width="940" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>'));
```

This ends the URL on < or white space.

Better solution would be to match only the letters and numbers that Youtube uses as video ids, something like ([a-zA-Z0-9]+), but I can't remember what characters are allowed in the id.

Comment: Thanks Oiva that put me on the right track. For Youtube I used: ([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+) and for Vimeo I used: (\d+) // seems to all be working.